# Remove transparancy in Sydney theme's headerimage

Tags: themes, css, headers

I'm bulimg a Wordpress site on the Sydney theme. On some pages the header image is kind of transparent. Not on the start page, but on all the other sites (example here: https://www.ferienhof-rauchhaus.de/ferienwohnungen/) how can I fix the issue, so that the header image is not transparent on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not the image that is transparent. There is an overlay box on top of the image (and THAT is transparent). :-)

[image: Transparent overlay in Sydney Theme]

There are several ways to fix it.

### The clean way

To find the overlay in the backend and see if you can disable it. Or perhaps make it 100% transparent (`opacity: 0`). Depending on the theme, then this might not be an option, but I would guess that it is (somewhere).

I'm not familiar with that theme, specifically.

### The dirty way

You could simply add this to your themes custom styles:

`.sydney-hero-area .overlay {display: none !important;}`